# CakePHP question: How can i pass the id of a post/view to comment/view?

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, cakephp-1.3

I'm on posts/view/id now.

There are options to edit, delete comments from posts/view/id.

If i click edit link of any comment then comments/view/id will execute.

After editing comment i need to do =>

```
$this->redirect(array('controller'=>'posts','action' => 'view',$id));
```

Here $id will be the id of posts.

How can i get the id of posts in comments/view action.

This is comments/edit/id action =>

```
function edit($id) {
    $this->Comment->id = $id;
    if (empty($this->data)) {
        $this->data = $this->Comment->read();
    } else {
        if ($this->Comment->save($this->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your comment has been updated.');
            $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'posts','action' => 'view',$id));
        }
    }
}
```

This is the edit link for comment =>

```
echo $this->Html->link('Edit', array('controller'=>'comments','action'=>'edit',$comment['Comment']['id']));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't there be $this->data['Comment']['post_id'] field available in comments/view? Unless you have some unorthodox relationship between Post and Comment. So `$this->redirect(array('controller'=>'posts','action' => 'view',$this->data['Comment']['post_id']));`

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your comment database table defines a foreign key field which leads to the post the comment belongs to? At least that would be the best practice for such a case, I guess.
If you have it implemented like that you can easily get the post_id by using this foreign key field of your currently viewed comment.

However, you might have chosen a different approach to connect posts an models. I think using that connection would be the easiest way to get the post_id. But wo would need some more information about your implementation then.